# Why is my application force-closing?

Tags: android, api, location, forceclose

I am trying to use google maps api for the first time, however my application keeps crashing whenever I start it. I deployed it to my android device and not to any emulator. This is the tutorial I used, and my code is essentially the same:-
[Tutorials point google maps tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm)

Sorry I couldn't be more specific since I do not know what is going wrong. Here is the log file I copied from logcat.

```
02-11 02:55:44.351: D/ActivityThread(1779): handleBindApplication:com.google.android.gms.wearable
02-11 02:55:44.351: D/ActivityThread(1779): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-11 02:55:44.351: D/ActivityThread(1779): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-11 02:55:44.531: I/MultiDex(1779): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
02-11 02:55:44.531: I/MultiDex(1779): install
02-11 02:55:44.531: I/MultiDex(1779): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, false)
02-11 02:55:44.551: I/MultiDex(1779): loading existing secondary dex files
02-11 02:55:44.561: I/MultiDex(1779): load found 2 secondary dex files
02-11 02:55:44.571: I/MultiDex(1779): install done
02-11 02:55:44.591: I/ProviderInstaller(1779): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
02-11 02:55:44.611: D/LocationInitializer(1093): Restart initialization of location
02-11 02:55:44.631: I/dalvikvm(1779): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getUserProfiles, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.y.a
02-11 02:55:44.631: W/dalvikvm(1779): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1110: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getUserProfiles ()Ljava/util/List;
02-11 02:55:44.631: D/dalvikvm(1779): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0035
02-11 02:56:48.241: D/ActivityThread(2361): handleBindApplication:com.google.android.gms
02-11 02:56:48.241: D/ActivityThread(2361): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-11 02:56:48.241: D/ActivityThread(2361): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-11 02:56:48.301: I/MultiDex(2361): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
02-11 02:56:48.301: I/MultiDex(2361): install
02-11 02:56:48.301: I/MultiDex(2361): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, false)
02-11 02:56:48.311: I/MultiDex(2361): loading existing secondary dex files
02-11 02:56:48.311: I/MultiDex(2361): load found 2 secondary dex files
02-11 02:56:48.321: I/MultiDex(2361): install done
02-11 02:56:48.591: I/ProviderInstaller(2361): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
02-11 02:56:48.711: D/LocationInitializer(2361): Restart initialization of location
02-11 02:58:46.871: D/ActivityThread(2762): handleBindApplication:com.google.android.gms.wearable
02-11 02:58:46.881: D/ActivityThread(2762): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-11 02:58:46.881: D/ActivityThread(2762): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-11 02:58:46.911: I/MultiDex(2762): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
02-11 02:58:46.911: I/MultiDex(2762): install
02-11 02:58:46.911: I/MultiDex(2762): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, false)
02-11 02:58:46.921: I/MultiDex(2762): loading existing secondary dex files
02-11 02:58:46.921: I/MultiDex(2762): load found 2 secondary dex files
02-11 02:58:46.921: I/MultiDex(2762): install done
02-11 02:58:46.931: I/ProviderInstaller(2762): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
02-11 02:58:46.961: D/LocationInitializer(2361): Restart initialization of location
02-11 02:58:46.971: I/dalvikvm(2762): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getUserProfiles, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.y.a
02-11 02:58:46.971: W/dalvikvm(2762): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1110: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getUserProfiles ()Ljava/util/List;
02-11 02:58:46.971: D/dalvikvm(2762): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0035
02-11 02:58:48.791: W/ActivityThread(2361): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
02-11 02:58:50.701: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
02-11 02:58:50.701: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Connection to https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
02-11 02:58:50.711: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Empty hitIds passed to deleteHits.
02-11 03:00:50.641: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
02-11 03:00:50.641: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Connection to https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
02-11 03:00:50.641: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Empty hitIds passed to deleteHits.
02-11 03:02:15.251: I/CastSocket(2361): 19 >= 18. Adding new CastClientAuthKeyManager.
02-11 03:02:50.681: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
02-11 03:02:50.681: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Connection to https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
02-11 03:02:50.681: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Empty hitIds passed to deleteHits.
02-11 03:04:00.431: I/EventLogService(2361): Aggregate from 1423602234108 (log), 1423602234108 (data)
02-11 03:04:00.601: W/EventLogAggregator(2361): Unknown tag: faceunlock
02-11 03:04:00.601: W/EventLogAggregator(2361): Unknown tag: snet
02-11 03:04:00.601: W/EventLogAggregator(2361): Unknown tag: snet_gcore
02-11 03:04:00.601: W/EventLogAggregator(2361): Unknown tag: snet_launch_service
02-11 03:04:50.751: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
02-11 03:04:50.751: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Connection to https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
02-11 03:04:50.751: W/GAV4(2361): Thread[Thread-2248,5,main]: Empty hitIds passed to deleteHits.
02-11 03:05:44.741: D/ActivityThread(4287): handleBindApplication:com.google.android.gms
02-11 03:05:44.741: D/ActivityThread(4287): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-11 03:05:44.751: D/ActivityThread(4287): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-11 03:05:44.921: I/MultiDex(4287): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
02-11 03:05:44.931: I/MultiDex(4287): install
02-11 03:05:44.931: I/MultiDex(4287): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, false)
02-11 03:05:44.951: I/MultiDex(4287): loading existing secondary dex files
02-11 03:05:44.951: I/MultiDex(4287): load found 2 secondary dex files
02-11 03:05:44.961: I/MultiDex(4287): install done
02-11 03:05:45.291: I/ProviderInstaller(4287): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
02-11 03:05:45.441: D/LocationInitializer(4287): Restart initialization of location
02-11 03:06:23.581: D/LocationInitializer(4287): Restart initialization of location
02-11 03:07:45.621: W/ActivityThread(4287): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
02-11 03:07:47.521: W/GAV4(4287): Thread[Thread-2299,5,main]: Exception sending hit: HttpHostConnectException
02-11 03:07:47.521: W/GAV4(4287): Thread[Thread-2299,5,main]: Connection to https://ssl.google-analytics.com refused
02-11 03:07:47.521: W/GAV4(4287): Thread[Thread-2299,5,main]: Empty hitIds passed to deleteHits.
```

Comment: Did you test on Emulator or a real device! What Android version is tested? Some Google service is not available in emulator or old Android

Comment: Device is a redmi 1S. Android 4.4.4. Google Maps as in the app, works fine on it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is actually a connection to Google analytics that is being refused.

A common reason for this is if you have a modified hosts file to block ads on your phone/device - this may also be blocking calls to Google Analytics.

Comment: How do I fix it then? Because I have another app I made which uses google analytics and it works just fine.

Comment: Well as a first test, I would disable or comment out the Goggle Analytics code and confirm that it does actually stop the issue. Also check it works on another non rooted device with no modified host file with the Analytics turned on. If yes to both of these then take a close look at the host file or other adware blocker/anti virus settings on the device with the issue.